# Roboguice Application @InjectView

Tags: android, android-layout, ioc-container, guice, roboguice

I am trying to use @InjectViews inside my android app but this doesn't seem to work. Here is the code for it. I've included the libraries and the jars into my android app and straight away extended from the RoboActivity class.

```
@InjectView(R.id.username)
EditText username;

@InjectView(R.id.firstname)
EditText firstname;

@InjectView(R.id.lastname)
EditText lastname;

@InjectView(R.id.email)
EditText email;

@InjectView(R.id.password)
EditText password;

@InjectView(R.id.confirmpassword)
EditText confirmpassword;

@InjectView(R.id.btnSubmit)
ImageButton submitbutton;

@InjectView(R.id.btnSignin)
ImageButton signinbutton;

String loginAvailabilityURL;
String createMemberURL;
```

This code is not working for me. What can be wrong? I can share the .java on pastie.org if required. Thanks.

Comment: here is the link to the java code http://pastie.org/private/qufw9e3iivdhhbsaflbzw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you also create an `Application` class that extends from `RoboApplication`, and configured  your module, as explained in the ["installation instructions"](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Installation)?

Comment: well, i did that but couldn't understand what kind of module do i need to create?

Comment: For starting a project, you don't need to do anything in particular, just create the application class like it's stated in the documentation, where your `addApplicationModules()` doesn't do anything. Create this class and add it to the manifest. That should get it working.


As you start implementing more classes and use Injection more heavily, you'll need a proper module to do your custom bindings.

Comment: Ahh. Now you saved me at least 2hrs :)